# Android achartengine getCubeLineChartView : add series with different smoothness

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(context, dataset, renderer, smoothness) to return a multiple axis XY view. (1 X axis and 2 Y axis)

I would like to add a new serie to the existing view chart but with a different smoothness. Is it possible and how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was designed on a per chart basis, not on a per series basis. So the answer is that you cannot.

However, you still have some choices:

- using a multiple XY chart
- building the `CubicLineChart` instance yourself and adding it to a view

Comment: Thx. Is there anyway then to use the existing smoothing method to one serie only ?